# Android instance of parent activity

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-intent

I have 2 activities, A & B for example.
I navigate to Activity B within Activity A using `startActivity()`

My question is when I'm on Activity B, how can I get access to activity A ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It really depends on what you want to do, and why you think you need that access. One thing you can do is pass data into an activity using `intent.putExtra` and then `startActivityForResult` and listen for results in `onActivityResult`. Can you give more information on what exactly you want to do?

To perform a method when an activity finishes, call the 'child' activity like this:

```
Intent child = new Intent(this, ChildActivity.class);
startActivityForResult(child, CHILD_CODE);
```

where `CHILD_CODE` is a nonnegative integer field. Now, you have to set a result in the 'child' activity (the one you started with `onActivityResult`).

```
    Intent resultIntent = new Intent();
    setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, resultIntent);
    finish();
```

now in your 'parent' activity, implement the `onActivityResult` method like this:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    switch (requestCode) {
    case CHILD_CODE:
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            yourMethod();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, What I want to do is to call a method on Activity A within Activity B,

Comment: @GuyDor: I don't think it's a good idea. Depending on the activity launch mode which is configured in manifest there can be more than one instnace of activity. Maybe you'd better implement the functionality you need in extended Application?

Comment: Use methods belong to another `Activity` is bad and really bad. It goes against the software design concept, bad practice. Make Loose coupling instead.

Comment: Thanks, so is there any way to determinate when I 'finish()' Activity B so I can call my method on Activity A ???

Answer (score 2):

To access functionality that is shared between Activities, it is a best practice to move that functionality to an Application class, or some other form of Singleton. The reason for that is the activity lifecycle does not allow you to be certain that the exited activity still exists while the focused activity is running. So you need to use an object that is able to be persistent between activities, even of Activity.finish() is called on either activity.

Here is documentation on the Application class.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html

You can access the application from within any activity by calling

```
this.getApplication();
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use a singleton class that can be accessed by both Actvity?